# Using graph-api/fql, How do I get the post/comment that caused a notification?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I can traverse the list of notifications by using FQL. Great. Now, how do I figure out how to get the post/comment to which the notification applies?

Example:
The notification is: "UserX commented on your post!"

From the fql table returned, how do I find the post_id or the xid for said comment so that I can find the post and the list of comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the REST API notifications.getList - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/notifications.getList/

You do not need any permissions beyond the basic.

This will return data including, object_id and object_type.

If object_type is "stream" you can query the stream table with the post_id  field set to the object_id from the notifications.getList query. You can get the comments from the stream table.

Example snippet of notifications.getList response:

```
<notifications list="true">
  <notification>
    .
    .
    <object_id>12345678_1001251985851</object_id>
    <object_type>stream</object_type>
    <icon_url>http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yr/r/B4fl7q9VLz5.gif</icon_url>
 </notification>
```

Your follow-on query:

```
SELECT comments FROM stream WHERE post_id='12345678_1001251985851'
```

Comment: Looks good - no longer need it though. Thanks for the answer!